# Unable to Install Wx - Strawberry Perl on Windows 10

Tags: perl, wxwidgets

While trying to install Wx for Strawberry Perl I am receiving the following error:

> gcc -c -o gcc_mswudll\wxregex_regcomp.o  -O2 -mthreads  -DHAVE_W32API_H -DNDEBUG -I....\include -I....\lib\gcc_dll\mswu -D__WXMSW__  -D_UNICODE -m64  -MTgcc_mswudll\wxregex_regcomp.o -MFgcc_mswudll\wxregex_regcomp.o.d -MD -MP ../../src/regex/regcomp.c
>       ../../src/regex/regcomp.c:1:0: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in 
>       makefile.gcc:5702: recipe for target 'gcc_mswudll\wxregex_regcomp.o' failed gmake: *** [gcc_mswudll\wxregex_regcomp.o] Error 1
>       system: gmake -f makefile.gcc all  UNICODE=1 MSLU=0 BUILD=release SHARED=1  DEBUG_INFO=default DEBUG_FLAG=1 LDFLAGS=" -m64" CPPFLAGS="-m64": 512 at inc/My/Build/Win32.pm line 284.
>         MDOOTSON/Alien-wxWidgets-0.67.tar.gz
>         D:\Perl\perl\bin\perl.exe ./Build -- NOT OK
>       Stopping: 'install' failed for 'Alien::wxWidgets'.

So this actually seems to be in the compile itself?  Using CPAN to install.  Not sure where to go from here.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core problem is the line

```
sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
```

so you are using the `-m64` option on a gcc that doesn't support 64-bit

Ordinarily I would expect the only gcc in your path to be the one that comes with Strawberry Perl, so are you using Cygwin or something that is causing the build to pick up the wrong compiler?

Comment: I had not thought about that.  I am trying several different programming languages for fun, and I know a number of them install there own gnu compiler toolchains.  I did think that was the issue and installed the latest mingw_64 release.  But let me work through my path variables and see if thats the issue.

Comment: @NateWells: You should make sure that the whole tool chain needed to build the module comes from the Strawberry Perl installation, including `perl.exe` and `dmake.exe`, otherwise you may end up with an incompatible module

Comment: Beautiful....  Yes that was the issue.  I am simply going to create some batch scripts to set my path correctly when I work in different languages.  Thank you.